# Evaluate@Table in a Plot can be accessed in another plot?

Tags: plotting

```
r1 = Plot[Evaluate@Table[xl[j, k, 0], {k, .01, 1, .1}], {j, 3/32, 2}, 
       PlotRange -> {{3/32, 2}, {.4, 4}}, AxesOrigin -> {3/32, .4}]
```

plots for me the complicated `xl` function (complex Bessel functions of `k`) as ordinate vs `j` absicca at various parameters `k` through, essentially contours of `k`.

Now I need to plot in the same `xl` by `j` space contours of new functions of the `k` (and `xl` and `j`). There is no way to algebraically invert `k` as a function of `xl` and `j`. Is the `Table` generated in the first plot any use? I don't really understand what the `Evaluate@Table` is doing

Comment: Please include the function `xl`, preferably a simplified version of the one you're using if it's too complicated.

Comment: `Table` is making multiple functions to be plotted. `Evaluate` is necessary because `Plot` is `HoldAll`.

Comment: Anyway, look at `ContourPlot`.

Comment: xl is the smaller root of a quadratic equation in x and j with coefficients from  the real and imaginary parts of the Theodorsen function which is a rational function of Bessel functions of the second kind of I*k

Comment: put the actual code for `xl` in the question ( or make up a simpler example to illustrate the point if it is too complicated )

Comment: I tried to paste in output graphs but that just produces reams of code

Comment: Why can't I paste graphics into a comment?

Comment: edit the question with whatever you need to add.